# Split line items to 3 rows in Excel

Tags: excel

I have an Excel sheet I need to get items split up on 3 different rows. Currently, my line items are all on the same row. The first line needs to create the Ad Group, the second line creates the text ad and url, the third line adds the keyword.

Please see the Google link, it contains two sheets, one called wrong and the other called right.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CH_zI6Waky0YCcArCvjAa4x3YbEt8rMEbybZRI-dOoc/edit?usp=sharing

I would greatly appreciate any help in fixing this. I have 30k+ products to do this to.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is tested and will split your current lines into 3 as you described in a new sheet so the original data isn't altered.

```
Sub SplitAds()

Dim thissheet As Worksheet
Set thissheet = ActiveSheet

Sheets.Add
Dim newsheet As Worksheet
Set newsheet = ActiveSheet

'Copy Headers
thissheet.Range("A1").EntireRow.Copy
newsheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)

Dim newrow As Long
For x = 0 To thissheet.Range("A65535").End(xlUp).Row
If Not thissheet.Range("A2").Offset(x, 0).Value = "" Then
thissheet.Range("A2:C2").Offset(x, 0).Copy
'Copy & Paste A:C
newsheet.Range("A2").Offset(newrow, 0).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
newsheet.Range("A2").Offset(newrow + 1, 0).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
newsheet.Range("A2").Offset(newrow + 2, 0).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
'Set Type
newsheet.Range("L2").Offset(newrow, 0).Value = thissheet.Range("L2").Offset(x, 0).Value
newsheet.Range("L2").Offset(newrow + 1, 0).Value = thissheet.Range("L2").Offset(x, 0).Value
newsheet.Range("L2").Offset(newrow + 2, 0).Value = thissheet.Range("L2").Offset(x, 0).Value
'Set D:J on 2nd
thissheet.Range("D2:J2").Offset(x, 0).Copy
newsheet.Range("D2").Offset(newrow + 1, 0).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
'Set Keyword on 3rd
newsheet.Range("K2").Offset(newrow + 2, 0).Value = thissheet.Range("K2").Offset(x, 0).Value
newrow = newrow + 3
End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to use that. looks like a macro? please tell me how to implement. thanks!

Comment: this actually creates 9 lines for each ad group. this code doesn't take into account the blank rows, which it needs to.

Comment: I updated it to account for blank rows. Is the raw data just like the "wrong way" sheet?